# Hosted wcf service in IIS dont response to other computers?

Tags: iis, wcf

HI

I develop the wcf service for hosting in IIS. test service in computer(which is service host in itself IIS) and as result this service work fine.

But When I try use that service from other Computer, service not responding and service cant be find!!!

Comment: I GIVE YOU MORE INFO!! see this link for Server/Client Config!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887776/wcf-error-the-client-and-service-bindings-may-be-mismatched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be:

- A security problem, what are the security settings on IIS?
- The port is blocked, what firewall settings do you have?

Or that you have an address with localhost (as already answered)

Comment: I use avast anti-virus(had fire-wall). As Default security config anonymous access is enable and user is IUSER. My Computer joined to domain-controller(AD). In that case i can locally connect to service and get Response but others (others computer in Domain) can see that service("can not find web page" error on IE).
 Also In Server Config(mean service) i don't set any Address for my service. so after hosting in IIS, service create this address with no ports : "http://localhost/Services/AdminCentralService.svc"
  Even when change "localhost" to "My-Computer-Name" I can access to service locally

Comment: Thanks to you. Every time i try find solution for my problems(specially wcf problem), your answers and post help me to find right solution.

Comment: My problem still exist. So what do i do?

Comment: Was the problem not solved by correcting the server name in the config file?

Comment: Damn, windows Fire-Wall prevent requests