# Error while invoking WCF web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have referenced WCF service in class library and that class library in a web application. When I tried to invoke a method from the service I am getting below exception.

```
"Content Type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:901bc2e6-6d57-4363-9f99-41ca4884ce16+id=1";start-info="text/xml" was not supported by service https://URL_OF_Service/.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched."
```

Here is my configurations

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CoreSoapBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://URL_OF_Service/" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="CoreSoapBinding" contract="ContractName"
          name="CoreSoapPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And I created binding object in the application and passed to the service.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            binding.Name = "CoreSoapPort";
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
            binding.AllowCookies = false;
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            Encoding textencoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            binding.TextEncoding = textencoding;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
```

I tried changing the configuration to multiple to match the server configuration. But no luck.

Comment: The error message is saying mtom content type (multipart/related) isn't supported by the service. Why do you think you need to specify mtom in your binding configured by code?

Comment: I think it is for you [WCF Error: the client and service bindings may be mismatched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887776/wcf-error-the-client-and-service-bindings-may-be-mismatched) Hope it helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887776/wcf-error-the-client-and-service-bindings-may-be-mismatched Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your message encoding configuration to [MTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496186/error-consuming-webservice-content-type-application-xopxml-does-not-match-ex)? IMHO, I think you should not used both configuration file and programmatically to configure your WCF service because it will give you a lot of headache. I suggest to stick to one, it's either configuration file or programmatically.

Comment: In the above code I have mentioned this.  binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;

Comment: I didn't mention that is should be in configuration file.

Comment: I have the latest configurations as     <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CoreSoapBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://URL_OF_Service/" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="CoreSoapBinding" contract="ContractName"
          name="CoreSoapPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

Comment: Your latest configuration has semi-colon after URL_OF_Service? It that a typo I guest.

Comment: That is a typo. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because of binding mismatch.
You server binding is a **BasicHttpBinding**, and your client is a **CustomBinding**.

As your service are using **BasicHttpBinding**, try to configure your client with same binding, but, if you want to use Soap12, you will need to configure your server side as **CustomBinding**, something like this:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
            SymmetricSecurityBindingElement ssbe =
                SecurityBindingElement.CreateSspiNegotiationBindingElement(true);
            // Add the SymmetricSecurityBindingElement to the BindingElementCollection.
            binding.Elements.Add(ssbe);
            binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());
            binding.Elements.Add(new HttpTransportBindingElement());
```

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope it helps.